# How to set up custom color scale with multiple sub-parts in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I' trying to set up a custom colorScale for my legend. The Result should look like this:

[image: Custom Color Scale]

Due to the smooth Transitions it probably should be a `d3.scaleLinear()` but no matter what I try I can't figure out the way. I've tried  `d3.scaleThreshold()` which at least seem to differentiate the domain-parts well enough.

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
                   .domain([20,35,50])
                   .range( ["#3AAA35", "#FCEA10", "#F39200", "#E30613", "#582123"] );
```

This seems to produce the best output right now, as in: each part gets its discrete color to the threshold.

I've tried something like this, but that did also not work at all:

```
.range([ d3.interpolateRgb("#3AAA35", "#FCEA10")),
         d3.interpolateRgb("#FCEA10", "#F39200"),
         d3.interpolateRgb("#F39200", "#E30613"),
         d3.interpolateRgb("#E30613", "#582123")]);
```

This looks simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a threshold scale, you can use more than 2 values in the linear scale range and domain, creating a piecewise scale:

```
const colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 20, 35, 50, 100])
  .range(["#3AAA35", "#FCEA10", "#F39200", "#E30613", "#582123"]);
```

This is the result:

```js
const colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 20, 35, 50, 100])
  .range(["#3AAA35", "#FCEA10", "#F39200", "#E30613", "#582123"]);

const w = 550,
  h = 40;

const canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("canvas")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

const context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

for (let i = 0; i < w; i++) {
  context.fillStyle = colorScale(i / (w / 100))
  context.fillRect(i, 0, 1, h);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```